# Manually choose the colors of ggplots in R for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to **manually choose the color of three plots created in a double for-loop**. However, when I run the code below, the plots (maps) have no points displayed and I have these warming messages.

What can I do to make this work?

```
library(ggplot2)
# Data frame (see below)
# Map
    FR <- map_data("world") %>% filter(region=="France")
# List periods and scenarios to plot
    periods <- c("2041-2070", "2071-2100")
    ssp <- c("ssp126", "ssp370", "ssp585")
# List of colors
    cols <- c("yellow","orange","red")
    names(cols) <- ssp
# Loop to create plots
for (j in periods) {
  for (k in ssp) {
    p <- ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data = FR, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill="grey", alpha=0.3) +
      geom_point( data=(df[grep(j, df$Period),] %>% .[grep(k, .$Scenario),]), 
                  aes(fill=Period, x=x, y=y, color=Period), size = 1) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = cols[k])

    assign(paste("p", j, k, sep = "_"), p) 
  }
}

Warning messages:
1: Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour 
2: Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour 

# Merge plots
library(ggpubr)
g1 <-ggarrange(`p_2041-2070_ssp370`,`p_2071-2100_ssp585`, ncol=1)

Warning messages:
1: Removed x rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`). 
2: Removed x rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

Some ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue. All six plots have points. And I don't get a warning about `Duplicated aesthetic ...`. In general this warning indicates you put `color=` two times inside `aes()`. Moreover, as your are mapping on color you probably want `scale_color_manual` instead of `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: Thank you! I just deleted `color=Period` in `aes()` and kept `color = cols[k]` and it works. Finally, correcting the code I made to ask the question here, I didn't take the time to test it fully, but it does work! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** problem solved thanks to @stefan comment. Deleting `color=` in `aes()` and only keep `colour = cols[k]` in `geom_point`. As in code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Map
    FR <- map_data("world") %>% filter(region=="France")
# List periods and scenarios to plot
    periods <- c("2041-2070", "2071-2100")
    ssp <- c("ssp126", "ssp370", "ssp585")
# List of colors
    cols <- c("yellow","orange","red")
    names(cols) <- ssp
# Loop to create plots
for (j in periods) {
  for (k in ssp) {
    p <- ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data = FR, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill="grey", alpha=0.3) +
      geom_point( data=(df[grep(j, df$Period),] %>% .[grep(k, .$Scenario),]), 
                  aes(fill=Period, x=x, y=y), 
                  colour = cols[k], size = 1) 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first warning it looks like you are mapping the "Period" variable to both the "fill" and "color" aesthetics in the "geom_point" layer. Try removing the "color" mapping to see if it resolves the issue.

The second warning message suggests that some of your data points might have missing values. You can either  remove them or impute them using methods like mean imputation.

Comment: Thanks for yous suggestion, I try to remove "color" mapping but it did not solve the problem. And for the second answer, the problem happen when I try to choose colors (as the code I post here), because when I run exactly the same code but sets the default color to `black` in the loop, it works and the values are not missing and are displayed on the map. The problem really comes from the moment I try to manually choose the color of my plots in the loop.